# Why does Facebook like button show count for whole site but start working after using FB debug?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have `<fb:like>` buttons on all of my site's articles, and all the required meta tags in the header. When the article is first created, the 'like' count is somewhere around 318, and the 'share' button popup shares the link to the site homepage not the individual article.

If I paste the URL into the Facebook debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, it shows no errors AND the Like Button immediately starts working as expected (i.e. showing 0 likes)!

Why is this?! Is it just a bug?

**UPDATE:** example of working button: http://www.theanglenews.co.uk/news/article-c43c88bad8d/ratted-out-where-does-your-meat-come-from.html

example of non-working button: http://www.theanglenews.co.uk/fashion/article-c42897bf90a/do-you-pda.html

Comment: probably not a bug. can you give us a link to try it ourselves?

Comment: Added examples to illustrate!